# how do I perform a lookup in an xml transformation with a key based on position?

Tags: xml, xslt

Given this XML segment:

```
<characteristics>
    <characteristic>fuzzy</characteristic>
    <characteristic>moist</characteristic>
    <characteristic>purple</characteristic>
    <characteristic>lazy</characteristic>
</characteristics>

<objects>
    <object name="Gary">
        <characteristics>
            <characteristic>2</characteristic>
            <characteristic>3</characteristic>
        </characteristics>
    </object>
    <object name="Oscar">
        <characteristics>
            <characteristic>1</characteristic>
            <characteristic>3</characteristic>
            <characteristic>4</characteristic>
        </characteristics>
    </object>
</objects>
```

Each object's characteristics' values are the position of the desired element.  How would I transform the objects' characteristics to use the values in the first block? I *think* I'd need to use a key, but I don't know how to use the position() function in the definition.  My desired results would look something like this:

```
Gary
characteristics:
   moist
   purple

Oscar
characteristics:
   fuzzy
   purple
   lazy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a key then you can define it as `<xsl:key name="ck" match="/*/characteristics/characteristic" use="count(preceding-sibling::characteristic) + 1"/>` and then reference e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="object/characteristics/characteristic">
  <xsl:value-of select="key('ck', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the `/*/characteristics/characteristic` in the key's match pattern to distinguish the elements from those in the object, I have assumed that elements to be matched by the key are grandchildren of the root, your sample does not show that exactly, so you might need to adapt the match pattern.